# Show/hide, BringToFront/SendToBack a panel on Parent form when a Child Form on the MDI Parent Form closes or appears

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I need to hide a panel on the Parent Form when a Child Form on an MDI Parent Form closes & show back the panel on the Parent form when the Child Form is closed.

Currently am using SendtoBack() to show the Child Form infront of the Panel which is on the Parent Form , but when i close the Child Form, then the Panel doesn't appears back, even if i use :

`BringtoFront()`

OR

```
Panel1.Visible=true


    public partial class CHILD : Form
        {
      private void CHILD_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(CHILD_FormClosed);
            }

     void CHILD_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                PARENTForm P = new PARENTForm();
                P.panel1.BringToFront();
                P.panel1.Visible = true; 

            }
}




public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
   private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
            {
                CHILD P = new CHILD();
                P.Showg();
                P.MdiParent = this;
                P.BringToFront();
                panel1.SendToBack();
                panel1.Visible = false;
            }
    }
```

THIS ISN'T WORKING....PLEASE HELP..!

[image]

Comment: how you open/call your child form? child.ShowDialog() ?

Comment: @ibram: no, i am using CHILD.Show()

Comment: if you use showdialog() instead of show() your parent form will know if your child is closed and you can do your panel work in your parent form.

Comment: showdialog() is also not working

Comment: you don't need bringtofront and sendtoback for your panel, just use panel.visible if you just want to hide it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You creating new parent form in child form. You need to pass parent form object to child form and then use it to show/hide panel and set panel Modifiers property to public. 
For example...

Parent form:

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = false;
        ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
        childForm.MdiParent = this;
        childForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Child form:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Child_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParentForm parentForm = (ParentForm)this.MdiParent;
        parentForm.panel1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reniuz: ok sir, so what's the reason that when we create a new parent form in child form, then the panel isn't displayed? The constructor is called and InitializeComponent() method is executed , then why is panel not appearing?

Comment: Well you dont need another parent form so you dont need to create new one. You need to use just one instance of parent form. Can you post all your code?

Comment: @Reniuz:  sir i have added the image, can you help me with the code now please

Comment: @Reniuz: sir, your code, ITS GIVING ERROR:--- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.----WHEN I CLOSE THE CHILD FORM THEN ERROR APPEARS

Comment: I understand what you want to do :).OK. In your example code just try to change PARENTForm P = new PARENTForm(); statment to PARENTForm P = (PARENTForm)this.MdiParent; in closed event.

Comment: I updated code. When creating child form assign MdiParent = this; in close event grab parent from MdiParent propertie and set panel1.Visible = true;

Comment: i should not use your code then, just change the line you specified in my posted code?

Comment: I updated my code again...its working 100% i tried :) also remember to CHANGE panel1 modifiers property to public so you can access it in child form.

Comment: @Reniuz: SIR , so the line---parent = (Form1)this.MdiParent;--------- is remembering that the MDI PARENT of the CHILD form before it is closed is----> FORM1(PARENT FORM) ....is this the purpose of the line---

Comment: when you creating child form and assign childForm.MdiParent = this child form will store information about its parent form. And when you need to access parent just cast child form MdiParent property and you will have your parent form. The line parent = (Form1)this.MdiParent; just accessing parent form.

Comment: @Reniuz: and sir, this line--> ParentForm parentForm = (ParentForm)this.MdiParent;   it is saving the properties of the MdiParent of CHILDFORM into a new object parentForm of PARENTFORM????????

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code
in Parent Form

```
    private void MainMenu_ChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ChildForm frm = new ChildForm();
            frm.MdiParent = this;
            ShowHideMainPanel(frm);
            frm.Show();
    }

void ShowHideMainPanel(Form frm)
        {
            frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form_Closed);
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        void Form_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }
```

by assigning close event for child to show panel after its closing