# Child Form opens in Parent Form but is behind Parent form Text Box and Label

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a WinForms Application written in VB using Visual Studio 2017.  My Parent form (IsMDiContainer = true) has a menu control in which I have a click control event handler that I want to open a Child Form and show it on top of the controls withing the parent.

I have successfully written the code to show the ChildForm, however, it showed behind a Text Box that is in the Parent Form.  I used the SendToBack() method on the Text Box and now the Text Box disappears when the Child Form is called.  When I close the Child Form, the Text Box does not reappear.

I tried to use the comments @ [Show/hide, BringToFront/SendToBack a panel on Parent form when a Child Form on the MDI Parent Form closes or appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040566/show-hide-bringtofront-sendtoback-a-panel-on-parent-form-when-a-child-form-on-t) for a similar issue, but was unable to understand or use it in Visual Studio 2017.  I have tried in the Parent form to Public Partial Class ParentForm : Form and Public ParentForm() indicated in those comments.  Visual Basic Tells me that ParentForm() conflicts with a variable in the base class of the Container Control.

Should I be trying to do this in the Components AS IContainer in find in Solution Explorer under my Parent Form?  Basically, I want to call the Child Form from the Parent MenuTool and have the Child Form be out front of any controls on the Parent Form and when I close the Child Form, I need the Parent Form controls visible and usable.

Comment: It is a basic Z-order problem, MDI child windows have the dark gray client window as their parent.  Any controls you put on the parent will overlap them.  You must use a panel and dock it to one side, that makes the client window shrink and no more overlap can occur.

Comment: Thanks.  So how do I direct the Child Form into that panel once I have made it and anchored it?  Will this panel be visible on the Parent Form all the time as kind of "dead" space until the Child is launched?

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond right away.  I was on the wrong page and got back and refreshed.

Comment: @braX Do I put the panel into the Parent or the Child form?  I put a panel anchored to the far upper right of my Parent Form.  This definitely shows up when I run, but my Child Form does not interact with it.  I expected from the above advice, that there must be a way to direct the Child into the Panel or am I thinking of it wrong?  Do I put the panel in the Child Form and if so, how does the fact that the Child Form has a panel make it show without overlapping controls in the Parent Form?

Comment: Figured it out doing a bit more research.  Had to put all the controls into the panel and dock the panel to one side.  I then had to resize both the Child and the Parent to accommodate the Child when called otherwise I get a slider bar to view the Child.  I don't like the grey client bit left on the opposite side where the Child ends up.  It makes the GUI look awkward.  Anyway, thanks for helping out a Newby!!